# How to install browser extensions on saucelabs?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, saucelabs, geckodriver

I want to install an browser extension before my tests starts. I read on the documentation [here](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/An+Introduction+to+Pre-Run+Executables) that I should create a prerun executable to do this for me. However I am not sure how to this. I have no experience with creating executables

Comment: [This](https://blog.tentamen.eu/run-chrome-with-extension-on-saucelabs/) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the pre-run will only upload the extension onto the SauceLabs Virtual Machine, it won't install it onto the respective browser.

If you want the extension to be installed on the browsers, you may want to consider setting a custom Firefox profile or Chrome options.

Here is a simple Java Example for setting a firefox profile (make sure to use the full path otherwise you will likely get an error):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(new File(<PATH TO EXTENSION>));
caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
```

Comment: This answer is unfortunately now a perfect example of why instead of adding a link, you quote the content that is on the link...